# Keyboard keeps vibrating, even though "vibrate on tap" is off?

Tags: keyboard, vibration

I recently factory reset my phone, I have Android 7.1.1. I want to disable the vibrations when typing. I go to Settings, Sound, Other sounds, and all options are OFF there, including "Vibrate on tap".

However, my  default keyboard keeps vibrating :(

How do I completely silence my keyboard?

Device: LG Nexus 5X

Comment: Stop vibrations from a specific app this way: [How to determine which app is causing vibration?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your version of Android.

Samsung Touchwiz-based phones and many others have the ability to control key press vibration intensity. Some more pure ASOP phone do not, such as official Google phones, or LineageOS.

One answer is to change keyboard. Both SwiftKey and GBoard offer the option to override the system sound and vibration settings.

Answer (score -2):

You can try Setting, Trigger: application launched > keyboard; Action > vibrate enable / disable >

Comment: Does setting have this? Or you simply copied what was suggested in comment and trying to pass off as answer? Please clarify. Downvoted -1

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that's not it. Note that I'm not referring to a vibration when I launch or open or close an application. It's just when typing anything, in any app.

Comment: Note that this answer was actually about the [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) app which was mentioned in the original (now deleted) comment, not the Android Settings.