# How to determine which app is causing vibration?

Tags: vibration

I have a Moto G6 Play that vibrates like it is getting notifications but it's not. The vibration is inconsistent and seems random so I would like to know if there is a logcat or something I can run to log which app is calling the vibration so that I can shut it off? The same thing happens on my wife's phone, same model, and it does my head in. The device is running Android 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the `dumpsys` method explained in the [other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215652/218526), you can use Android's hidden (kind of) permission manager `appops` to get recently allowed vibrator requests, e.g. in last minute. From `adb shell`:

```
for pkg in $(pm list packages | sed 's/package://')
do
    echo "$pkg $(appops get $pkg VIBRATE)" | grep 'time=+[0-9]*s'
done
```

`pm` is the package manager which lists all installed packages. `appops` determines when last time each package made a vibration request and if it was allowed or rejected.

Result can be further filtered by piping output through `awk '{printf "%-12s%-20s%s\n",$3,$4,$1}'`:

```
allow;      time=+15s659ms      com.termux
allow;      time=+6s458ms       com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
```

Termux made a vibration 15 seconds back. Also the request can be denied:

```
~$ appops set com.termux VIBRATE deny
```

Now the output will be like this:

```
deny;       time=+9s500ms       com.termux
allow;      time=+6s392ms       com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
```

And a shameless self-promotion. If not comfortable with CLI, you can use my open-source app [Permission Manager X](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) to get and set AppOps:

[image]

Comment: To clarify, will I need root access to run that command or will an up to date adb installation suffice? Thanks again.

Comment: @Badger all commands work without root on adb shell, but not on a terminal emulator app.

Answer (score 5):

The next time your device vibrates, connect it to a PC with [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) already setup, and issue this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys vibrator
```

In the output, along with the pattern of vibration  you would be able to see the UID and package name of the app that caused the vibration in the device recently. For example, in my OnePlus 6 (Android 8.1.0) device it showed this output:

```
Previous vibrations:
  , startTime: 95325556, effect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 250], mAmplitudes=[0, -1], mRepeat=-1}, usageHint: 5, uid: 10122, opPkg: com.textra
  , startTime: 95346005, effect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 250], mAmplitudes=[0, -1], mRepeat=-1}, usageHint: 5, uid: 10122, opPkg: com.textra
  , startTime: 95428005, effect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 250], mAmplitudes=[0, -1], mRepeat=-1}, usageHint: 5, uid: 10122, opPkg: com.textra
  , startTime: 95516412, effect: OneShot{mTiming=50, mAmplitude=-1}, usageHint: 0, uid: 1001, opPkg: com.android.incallui
  , startTime: 95572994, effect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 250], mAmplitudes=[0, -1], mRepeat=-1}, usageHint: 5, uid: 10122, opPkg: com.textra
  , startTime: 96868723, effect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 250], mAmplitudes=[0, -1], mRepeat=-1}, usageHint: 0, uid: 1000, opPkg: android
  , startTime: 97144598, effect: OneShot{mTiming=200, mAmplitude=-1}, usageHint: 0, uid: 10130, opPkg: com.phonepe.app
  , startTime: 97187986, effect: OneShot{mTiming=200, mAmplitude=-1}, usageHint: 0, uid: 10130, opPkg: com.phonepe.app
  , startTime: 98229901, effect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 300], mAmplitudes=[0, -1], mRepeat=-1}, usageHint: 0, uid: 10133, opPkg: com.arlosoft.macrodroid
```

The string next to `opPkg:` is the package name of the app that caused the vibration at a certain time. The list is in chronological order with the most recent entry at the bottom. To get the app's name out of the package name, see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198095/96277).

Comment: On Pie I get human readable time: `startTime: Aug 10, 2019, 2:05:20 AM, effect: Prebaked{mEffectId=0, mEffectStrength=1, mFallback=true}, originalEffect: null, usageHint: 13, uid: 10151, opPkg: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin`