# Disable vibrations for notifications on Xiaomi Mi A3

Tags: notifications, 9.0-pie, xiaomi, vibration

I have a Xiaomi Mi A3 on Android 9. I want to disable the vibration when a notification arrives for all apps.

I did not know that by disabling notifications, I won't be able to receive calls since notifications for the calls also did not appear, only the ringtone played, and upon unlocking the phone there was no display of who was calling.

Somehow I enabled notification for all apps but it is vibrating each time.

How do I disable vibrations for notifications like messages on Telegram, Facebook, WhatsApp?

Comment: Using `appops`: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526

Answer (score 1):

You wont find any vibration settings to change in *Sound settings.* You will have go for *Settings › Accessibility › Vibration&Haptic › Notification* to turn off vibration.

Comment: Ok I checked there is accessibility->interaction control->vibration->ring and notification vibration / touch vibration I turned both off.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please don't use "txtspeak" / "SMS lingo" on SE sites, but rather fully spell each word. Many users here are no native English speakers, and some already have a hard enough time to follow normal English.