# How can I see which applications is reading the clipboard?

Tags: privacy, copy-paste

Upon reading [TikTok says it will stop accessing clipboard content on iOS devices](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/26/21304228/tiktok-security-ios-clipboard-access-ios14-beta-feature), I wonder: How can I see which applications is reading the clipboard?

Comment: If your device is rooted, and you use Xposed: XPrivacyLua shows such things (if an app has tried to access, and if so how often and what time last).

Comment: Use AppOps to get status of operation `READ_CLIPBOARD` like this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526

Answer (score 2):

We can do some scripting with AppOps.

Create `/sdcard/clipboard_history.sh`:

```
for pkg in $( pm list packages | sed 's/package://' )
do
    ( appops get $pkg READ_CLIPBOARD; appops get $pkg WRITE_CLIPBOARD ) |
    grep -i time= |
    while read -r line
    do
        echo $line | grep ' allow; ' | sed 's/time=+//'
        echo $line | grep -v ' allow; ' | sed 's/time=+[^ ]*//; s/rejectTime=+//'
    done |
    sed 's/[0-9]*ms//; s/[:;]//g; s/_CLIPBOARD//; s/ago//g; s/$/& '"$pkg"'/'
done |
awk '{printf "%-10s%-14s%-20s%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

Run:

```
~$ adb shell sh /sdcard/clipboard_history.sh
WRITE     allow         19h48m7s            org.shadowice.flocke.andotp
READ      allow         2d1h46m12s          dev.ukanth.ufirewall
READ      ignore        26m16s              com.dv.adm.old
READ      deny          7h39m16s            com.google.android.gms
READ      foreground-R  1d2h43m6s           org.blackmart.market
WRITE     allow         6m48s               com.termux
READ      foreground    16s                 com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
READ      allow         1m17s               com.stackexchange.marvin
WRITE     allow         1m14s               com.stackexchange.marvin
```

Similar answer here: [Is there a way to log calls to device vibrator?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526)

Answer (score 1):

- Prior to Android 10, **all apps** could access clipboard by default without even asking for permission.
  Apps actually need a permission (that is automatically granted) to read the clipboard: `READ_CLIPBOARD` (from [XDA Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/stop-apps-reading-android-clipboard/)) - thanks to [Andrew in comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226282/how-can-i-see-which-applications-is-reading-the-clipboard#comment295093_226283)
- In Android 10, See [Privacy changes in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes),
  access to clipboard is limited to OEM apps only that have `READ_CLIPBOARD_IN_BACKGROUND` permission, which are keyboards and "apps in focus" (not sure what latter means)

> Unless your app is the default input method editor (IME) or is the app that currently has focus, your app cannot access clipboard data on Android 10 or higher

- TikTok would need to ask and be granted the same signature as OS since this permission is [Signature permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

> The system grants these app permissions at install time, but only when the app that attempts to use a permission is signed by the same certificate as the app that defines the permission.

Comment: In this kind of context "app in focus" should mean the app that's actively in use and displayed on the screen. Classically in OS jargon & programming "in focus" is referring to whatever is currently capturing user input.

Comment: @l3l_aze My confusion is more with the question - does any app that has focus gain access to clipboard? Answer according to me is yes but not sure

Comment: Ohh, I think I'm with you now. [Signature Permissions](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) (Ctrl + f `data sharing through permissions`) says: it allows apps to share code & data provided they're both signed with the same public key certificate (which is generated by devs). These are attached to apps by `apksigner`, so I don't believe the signatures could be OEM to the OS and the app wouldn't be given the special BACKGROUND permission except maybe if it's pre-installed (but IDK personally). Any app with focus will have access by default, based on your quote above.