# adb appops command error trying to disable vibration for a specific app in Android 10

Tags: adb, android-10

Referring to this excellent Q&A:
[How to determine which app is causing vibration?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215638/how-to-determie-which-app-is-causing-vibration/)
I opened an adb shell and ran:

```
for pkg in $(pm list packages | sed 's/package://')
do
    echo "$pkg $(appops get $pkg VIBRATE)" | grep 'time=+[0-9]*s'
done
```

which resulted in:

```
tesmath.calcy VIBRATE: allow; time=+11s553ms ago; duration=-18585d23h50m2s991ms
```

I then ran:

```
appops set tesmath.calcy VIBRATE ignore
```

but it resulted in the error:

```
appops set tesmath.calcy VIBRATE: inaccessible or not found
```

How can the app initiate vibrations but yet this adb command doesn't successfully disable them in my Android 10 device?

Comment: [In Android 10, once the user sets "Deny" or "Allow only while using" in the system, the settings in App Ops will never take effect (because uid mode set by the system is used first).](https://appops.rikka.app/guide/technical/system_behaviors/)

Comment: So maybe enable vibrations again in App's Notification Settings and then try again with ADB?

Comment: Edit: tried that, no change, however, turning off notifications entirely and turning them back on (leaving vibrations off) did work. Strange