# block particular apps from accessing vibration

Tags: permissions, vibration

I'm using Samsung S9 ( OneUI version 2.5, Android version 10 ).
Is there any way to stop a particular app from accessing the vibration feature of the phone?
Even if I turn on the silent mode and turn off the vibration for all notifications, certain apps keep on vibrating the phone even for minor actions. I find this really annoying and I want to block these apps from having access to the vibration feature. How to do this?

In detail :
I'm the kind of person who doesn't like the concept of vibration haptic feedback. I'm okay with my phone vibrating for essential notifications such as calls and texts when I'm in a meeting and my phone is in silent mode. However, I don't like the phone vibrating for silly things such as a key-press, or forwarding a video etc. It gives me a weird feeling and also vibration consumes the battery.

Recently this problem became really annoying, as Youtube introduced **segments** in videos. Now, when I try to forward the video using the progress bar, the phone gives a really strong vibration, Which is annoying and consumes a lot of power.

I looked in the settings of the Youtube app and there is no way to stop it from vibrating. Is there any way to block the youtube app from having access to the vibration motor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine which app is causing vibration?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215638/how-to-determine-which-app-is-causing-vibration). The question title doesn't include but my answer addresses "how to stop vibrations" as well.

Comment: Hi, Can you please post that as an answer here? Because the titles are so different, It would be easier for future references to find it if you answer it here.