# How do I find out what app is showing a toast?

Tags: toast-notifications

Several times a day my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy A51, Android 11) is showing this toast

> We're having trouble connecting. Check your network connection and try again.

If I stay offline this toast will return every few minutes. How can I find out which app is posting these toasts. And most importantly how do I get rid of them? Long-pressing the toast doesn't show anything.

Comment: You can use AppOps to get status of operation `TOAST_WINDOW` like this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Toaster app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mars3142.android.toaster) I found out that the toasts were coming from [SmartThings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.oneconnect) app. I have no idea what this app is for and I'm certainly not using it. In the settings I managed to uninstall it and I assume this will stop it from spamming me with toasts.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Android's [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) tool:

```
adb shell uiautomator events
```

Make sure you have [USB Debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html) enabled on your device.  Connect your device to a computer and open a terminal to run the above adb command.

Running this command will dump out system events - you will get a LOT of information.

For example, here's a Toast I created by setting an alarm with the Clock app:

> 11-27 16:31:32.510 EventType: TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT; EventTime: 6865213;
>   PackageName: com.google.android.deskclock; MovementGranularity: 0;
>   Action: 0 [ ClassName: android.view.ViewGroup; Text: [Alarm set for 15
>   hours and 59 minutes from now.]; ContentDescription: null; ItemCount:
>   -1; CurrentItemIndex: -1; IsEnabled: true; IsPassword: false; IsChecked: false; IsFullScreen: false; Scrollable: false; BeforeText:
>   null; FromIndex: -1; ToIndex: -1; ScrollX: -1; ScrollY: -1;
>   MaxScrollX: -1; MaxScrollY: -1; AddedCount: -1; RemovedCount: -1;
>   ParcelableData: null ]; recordCount: 0

Note the app in question is listed under `PackageName` as `com.google.android.deskclock;`.  This should give you a good idea which app the Toast has originated from.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the **[Toast Source](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.revanmj.toastsource)** app for that. It not only integrates the app icon and name with each toast message (first screenshot below), but also gives you a history of toasts you received and which app sent it:

[image: Toast Source] [image: Toast Source History]
<sup>*Toast Source* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.revanmj.toastsource); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Quite privacy friendly it doesn't even require the Internet permission (so no ads either). But as it uses accessibility services, it's unclear whether it will survice [Googles current purge](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/11/12/google-will-remove-play-store-apps-use-accessibility-services-anything-except-helping-disabled-users/).