# How to make calls ring (with sound) while messages vibrate?

Tags: notifications, calls, ringtone, vibration

This seems like a fairly basic thing but I'm having trouble nonetheless. I'd like my calls to ring (with sound) while messages vibrate (no sound). How do I do this?

- Setting sound mode to "sound" and turning notification volume down means calls ring, but I get no vibration.
- Setting sound mode to "vibrate" means messages vibrate, but I get no ringing for calls.

I am using Android 11 and have a Samsung Glaxy A71.

Comment: Grant Messages app the VIBRATE permission while disallow to the Phone app: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526. Or replace the stock Phone app with some other app which provides control over vibration behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution

1. The Ringtones (used by Calls) and Notification sounds (used by Messages) can be set to different audio.
2. For Notifications (under Settings->Sounds and Vibration), select a tone without audio.

As an example [Zedge](https://www.zedge.net/find/ringtones/no%20sound) has such ringtones.