# Disable vibration per app/Globally No Root

Tags: root-access, vibration, android-12

I would like to disable vibration for specific app or Globally. There is app for sound "App Volume Control Pro" that can do it for sound without root. Is there any app that can do that for vibration?

Comment: You can do that by setting `VIBRATE` AppOp permission of the app from `allow` to `ignore`. Please see my answer to [How to determine which app is causing vibration?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526)

Comment: No Root is the key.

Comment: Noted. You don't necessarily need root to set an AppOp permission. ADB privileges suffice.

Comment: Yes this is the answer xD.

Comment: Is there a command for sound/notifications?